# ngFor trackBy function with custom parameters

Tags: angular, ngfor, angularjs-track-by

The trackBy function (e.g. in an ngFor) provides two arguments: index and item (from the collection being iterated over).  Is there a way to pass additional information (as parameters?) to th trackBy function?

My case is that I might be iterating over a variety of types for each instance of my component (which contains the ngFor), with different identifying field names.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass a third parameter indicating which field in my item should be read.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`bind` method can help you to do this trick

**template.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackByFn.bind(this, 'name')">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```typescript
items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2'
  }
]
trackByFn(customParam, index, item) {
  return item[customParam];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*I know this question is over a year old now, but I'd like to add another option:*

You can create an Angular pipe that takes the additional parameter(s) as arguments and returns a [TrackByFunction](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction). The use of such pipe would look as follows:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: (myParameter | myTrackByFn)">
```

The code for the pipe looks as follows:

```typescript
@Pipe({ name: 'myTrackByFn' })
export class MyTrackByFnPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform<T>(myParameter: any): TrackByFunction<T> {
    return (index: number: item: T) => {
      // ...
    };
  }
}
```

One of the benefits that comes with this approach is that you can reuse the pipe across components, eliminating the need to reimplement a trackBy function in every component.

You can read more about this approach in [Ben Nadel's post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3579-using-pure-pipes-to-generate-ngfor-trackby-identity-functions-in-angular-7-2-7.htm).